# A string in PHP that doesn't make sense

Tags: php, dynamic-typing, weak-typing

I was experimenting with weak/dynamic typing properties of PHP in preparation for a test and was completely baffled by the output of this string concatenation. Can someone explain how this is even possible?

```
<?php echo  1 . "/n" . '1' + 1 ?><br />
```

output:

> 2

Comment: See if it makes more sense after you `echo intval("1/n1");` and look over [PHP's info on type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Comment: haha, I don't think that will make more sense but it will show the solution.

Comment: Also, [string conversion to numbers...](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Comment: @skj3gg I was thinking the same thing - at least the nonsense is documented.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski but how is 1/n1 == 1?

Comment: @ngin0xA That's described in the second link on string to number conversion.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks I appreciate the links, now it makes more sense.

Comment: This is giving expected output. <?php echo  1 , "/n" , '1' + 1 ?><br />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analysis:

```
echo  1 . "/n" . '1' + 1;
```

is equivalent to

```
//joined first 3 items as string
echo "1/n1"+1;
```

is equivalent to

```
//php faces '+' operator, it parses '1/n1' as number
//it stops parsing at '/n' because a number doesn't
//contain this character
echo "1"+1;
```

is equivalent to

```
echo 1+1;
```